# Downloading a base64 byte array into a file using ajax call

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have the below problem.

I need to send multiple files attached as part of JSON request and save it into database.

followed the below steps:

1. converted the uploaded file into base64 String and included in JSON with other values.
2. In server side, using java, converted the base64 string to byte[] and stored in database.

Issue with downloading the file retrieved from database.

I have written a controller method to return the byte[] from database and using XMLHttpRequest, i am trying to save the file. But getting file corrupted error while opening the saved file.

below is my javascript code:

```
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("POST", 'getAttachment/'+idTemp, true); 
            request.responseType = "blob";
            request.onload = function (e) {
               if (this.status === 200) {
                  // `blob` response
                  console.log(this.response);
                  var arr = this.response;
                  var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arr);
                  // create `objectURL` of `this.response` : `.pdf` as `Blob`
                  var file = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray]));
                  var a = document.createElement("a");
                  a.href = file;
                  a.download = this.response.name || fileNameTemp;
                  document.body.appendChild(a);
                  a.click();
                }
            }
            request.send();
```

Please note that, all types of files has to be stored and downloaded.